# INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK error

Tags: android, android-build

I know it's a recurring question over here at stackoverflow but none of the answers suggested that something is wrong with my project definitions

My Device (nexus 5) is running kitkat - version 4.4.4

Today i've updated sdk to include L version. I'm also using android studio 0.8.1.

i've updated `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'


buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard- rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.77'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.+'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.commonsware.cwac:camera:0.6.+'
}
```

My `AndroidManifest.xml` starts with:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.q.q"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="L" />
```

I've tried to play with it and move the min and targetSdk to build.gradle without any success.

It doesn't matter what i do, i still get failure [INSTALLED_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]

I just want to mention that i didn't use any L classes or styles yet...
Thanks!

Roy

Comment: If you are using `L` as your target you **must** use `L` as the min-sdk as well. This is a requirement for the developer preview. You can not yet build `L` apps that work on other devices as well (even if you don't use any class of it).

Comment: Yep i've discovered it yesterday. there is a workaround which is to download sdk 21 and use it but it's not really recommended